# Not receiving POST in PHP when using class contact-form from Bootstrap3

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, contact-form

I have a simple contact form in Bootstrap3. When I add the class "contact-form" the php is not receiving POST parameters, so the mail is sent void.

This is the form:

```
<div id="contact-section">
    <h3>Contacta con nosotros</h3>
    <div class="status alert alert-success" style="display: none"></div>
    <form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="sendemail.php">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="Nombre">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" required="required" placeholder="E-mail">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea name="message" id="message" required="required" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Introduzca su mensaje"></textarea>
        </div>                        
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Enviar</button>
        </div>
    </form>        
</div>
```

and this is the php:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $name =  @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'jcarlosrga@gmail.com';//replace with your email

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');
    $status = array(
        'type'=>'success',
        'message'=>'Gracias por el mensaje. Tan pronto como podamos, nos pondremos en contacto contigo.'.$name
    );
    echo json_encode($status);
    die;
?>
```

This is the jquery validation

```
// Contact form validation
var form = $('.contact-form');
form.submit(function () {'use strict',
    $this = $(this);
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {
        $this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
    },'json');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: have to tried with get, is that working with get?

Comment: Have you add role="form" into your form? Please read complete guide here: https://bootstrapbay.com/blog/working-bootstrap-contact-form/

Comment: I've just tried with get and it's the same problem

Comment: I added the role="form" also and it's still not working when I put the class "contact-form" to the form

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, `contact-form` is not a valid bootstrap class, try using `form-horizontal`.

If you defined the `contact-form` class somewhere, please share it with us.

Comment: You're right I forgot the jquery part:  
<code>
    // Contact form validation var form = $('.contact-form');
 `form.submit(function () {'use strict',`
  `$this = $(this);`
  `$.post($(this).attr('action'), function(data) {`
   `$this.prev().text(data.message).fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();`
  `},'json');`
  `return false;`
 `}); `

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class to the form cannot really preventing it from sending post data, unless you have a typo in your code and you're missing ending quotes or something like that (but it seems ok in your question).

To test this hypothesis, move the **method** and **action** attributes at the beginning, like this:

```
<form method="post" action="sendemail.php" id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" >
```

Comment: I've just added the jQuery validation